# Workflow to connect to android sqlite on windows without android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, nativescript

I'm on Windows 10 developing a Nativescript app and want to view the sqlite database embedded in the android app for debugging purposes. I can currently do this, but the workflow is too many steps. I'd like to not have to manually recopy the android app's database to my Windows box every time changes are made to the database.

My currently workflow is to open a command prompt and run

```
cd mydirectory
adb -d shell "run-as org.nativescript.myapp cp /data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/databases/mydatabase.db /sdcard/mydatabase.db"
adb pull /sdcard/mydatabase.db
```

Then using DataGrip I connect to mydirectory/mydatabase.db

I think android studio can connect to an android database, but since it's a Nativescript project Webstorm is being used. Even though I'm currently using DataGrip to view sqlite databases I'm open to using something else. Another option could be to get a database viewer on the phone, but I'd rather view it on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are are using **webStorm**, you can easily create a simple task to automate this code as a simple macro; to do the steps above; (you can script both the push and pull), then the last step is have it open up your favorite viewer.   So this it is a simple keystroke/or menu item to activate it.
See `File` -> `Settings`, then `Tools`, `External Tools`.

For those using **phpStorm**, it has built in sqlite viewer/editor, so you can script it to pull the latest files and then view/edit it inside phpStorm.